# Can't I find MySQL API for MinGW? [Windows 10]

Tags: c++, mysql, api, mingw

MySQL official site only provides me libs for VisualC++

I have a lib that works for MinGW which I found like 8 years ago, but of course, it doesn't work with later versions like MinGW 6.1.0

Is MinGW not supported anymore by MySQL? :(

PD: Well, another way would be to compile it, but I would like to avoid using CMake... but I won't discard it :/